# For loop over a range. Is there an elegant way to get the iteration number

Tags: c++

Let's say we have a for loop:

```cpp
for(char &ch : text){
    if(ch == 'a')
        std::cout << "Found 'a' at position: " << {a.index} << std::endl;
}
```

Is there an easy way to get `{a.index}`?

Of course I know I could do something like this:

```cpp
for(int i = 0; text[i] != '\0'; i++){
    if(text[i] == 'a')
        std::cout << "Found 'a' at position: " << i << std::endl;
}
```

or

```cpp
i = 0;
for(char &ch : text){
    if(ch == 'a')
        std::cout << "Found 'a' at position: " << i << std::endl;
    i++;
}
```

But I'm asking, because of educational purpose if there is some built-in way to do this.

Comment: There's an example on cppreference using [strstr](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strstr). I'd go with your second code snippet, though.

Comment: is `text` a string? For contiguous container you can use the difference between `&ch` and pointer to first element

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number yes `text` is a string. Your solution is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you

Comment: though I would only use it when its not needed in every iteration as is the case in your example.